# Ubuntu unable to boot from clean install

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, grub, grub2

Here's some background in case it will help: I've recently been having trouble booting my computer, as you might have guessed. For some background, it started when I tried to re-install some NVIDIA drivers after an update broke CUDA and lead to some poor video performance. However that led to some conflicts, and I totally lost the graphics, and couldn't get beyond the command line tty screen (ctrl+alt+f1). I tried a reboot - then it would just hang after selecting the Ubuntu 14.04 to boot up. Then I tried the boot repair cd to no avail (first of the two links below). As of now, trying to boot from it, I get the "error: no such device: 90cc5126-fb61-4bb20aafe-b9ad22f26644."; then it goes into a boot rescue command-line.

After that didn't work, I unplugged all of my hard drives, and hooked up a brand new one, and tried to install 16.04 on it, but again I couldn't boot. (this time the error just said to insert a boot device). I again tried the boot repair cd, but it didn't work again That's the second link below.

And of course, here is the paste bin for the hard drive with the old install (Ubuntu 14.04): I think something went pretty terribly wrong, because glancing at the below text, it looks as though there's no OS detected at all. https://paste.ubuntu.com/20470855/

and the new hard drive which has a clean install of 16.04 on it: http://paste.ubuntu.com/20469479/

I really appreciate any ideas that you'll have. I'm really not sure what it could be, but I'm a total novice with this aspect of any linux system, so I thought it would be good to reach out to you.

Thanks so much!

Comment: I got things to work now. I think had screwed up the CMOS settings to the point where it the bios/UEIF settings were somehow conflicting. Resetting all the CMOS settings to factory defaults fixed the problem, and I have a computer again! Thanks to anyone that put any thought into my problem!

Comment: welcome, i'm  glad you got your problem fixed and explain the basic's in comment. You can turn the comment into a answer with more detail,etc and mark the answer as the accepted answer. this gives you rep points and provides the site with a finished answer in case other readers have the same trouble. thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got things to work now. I think had screwed up the CMOS settings to the point where it the bios/UEIF settings were somehow conflicting. Resetting all the CMOS settings to factory defaults fixed the problem, and I have a computer again! Thanks to anyone that put any thought into my problem!